# Wordpress: How select query is generated in a Custom Post Type?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have this table that is generated in a Custom Post Type (CPT)
[image]

Is there an option that I can modify the query? For example, I have this post_type = 'my-type' in wp_posts table. I want to do a JOIN to have specific values with the table wp_postmeta - how can I do that? Where do I edit the query?

Comment: What's your actual goal? Sounds to me that what you want is to display additional columns with data from custom fields, is that it?

Comment: ... or maybe you want to list only some CPTs that have a certain value?

Comment: @cabrerahector Exactly i want to list only posts that have an specific value in its meta, for that i need to do a join, all of this is to have control in what an specific user can see

Comment: I think your concern is same as answered before. Please visit https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo